# Выполнить "обмен местами" пары цветов компонента C++

Tags: c++, winforms, color

```
System::Void CLCE_MouseDown(Object^ sender, System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventArgs^ e)
{
        if (e->Button == Windows::Forms::MouseButtons::Right)
        {   
            //запомнить BackColor, допустим, в переменную backColor
            this->BackColor = this->ForeColor; 
            this->ForeColor = backColor;
        }

}
```

Comment: эм, написать вместо комментария `Color backColor = this->BackColor;` ?

Comment: Упссс... Спасибо, работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас все даже в комментах написано...

> запомнить BackColor, допустим, в переменную backColor

```
if (e->Button == Windows::Forms::MouseButtons::Right)
{   
    //запомнить BackColor, допустим, в переменную backColor !!!
    Color backColor = this->BackColor;
    this->BackColor = this->ForeColor; 
    this->ForeColor = backColor;
}
```